# How to parse and convert a javascript string to a proper date formatting

Tags: javascript, string, date, time

I have a form on a website where the user will be typing in a date (and time) in the format `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss am` (or pm), and I need to convert that to `mm-dd-YY hh24:mi:ss`  However, I've never done any string parsing with javascript before, or converting 24-hour to 12 with am/pm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com).

Or use a regular expression to parse it as @Frits van Campen suggested.

Comment: Yes, moment is best

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions to parse the input. If you've never used regular expressions before search for a good tutorial on Google, I'm sure you'll find something.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [simple javascript date formatter](https://code.google.com/p/simple-javascript-date-formatter/source/checkout) for date formatting.
And another way is, you can split the Date object to get month,year,day etc values and then create expected format. For that you can refer [jsref_obj_date](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)